# Can I ask a question about having symptoms for an unknown disease?

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering if I can ask a question as such:

> Symptoms, including known symptoms and description of self, with history
>
> Possible diseases that I *could* have

I know that the best way to officially diagnose a disease is to go to the doctor, but I would like some community help on what it could be (in case it's not serious at all). I see in the FAQs/Tour that off-topic questions include "opinion-based" or "advice-seeking" questions, but I want it to be more identification, rather than advice (if you get what I mean).

I've noticed that some of the questions in this SE site is not identification, but rather questions along the lines of "what can this disease do". That's why I'm unsure if these "ID" questions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Asking what can cause a set of symptoms should be okay if you word it carefully so that it's a question about a symptom cluster and what could cause it rather it being a question about *your* symptoms. And don't ask for a single answer since that's probably impossible without an exam, full history, and lab work. All valid answers would probably be a list of possibilities for almost any set of symptoms.

Also watch out for being overly broad. For example, if you listed headache, fever and nausea, that set of symptoms will match virtually every infectious disease known so it's not a useful question.

***Above all, strictly avoid asking what to do about it*** because the answer will always be "see a doctor" followed by closure of your question.